# Failure to install modern .NET Framework on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, windows-update, .net-framework

I've tried to install anything past .NET Framework 4.5 on a Windows 8.1 desktop, and can't seem to succeed. The first attempt was through Windows Update, and it's pushed every update through except for KB3045563 with failure code 0x8007010B (it's the .NET Framework update)

I've tried repairing the current 4.5.2 .NET, using the Windows Update Troubleshooter, manually installing both the KB update and just newer versions of .NET Framework. I cleared the files under *Windows* -> *Software Distributions* -> *Downloads* and restarted, disabled antivirus, and now I don't know what to do.

I tried downloading 4.6.2 and 4.7.2 from the respective Microsoft download locations for more modern applications. I'm aiming for 4.7.2 in the end, but can't seem to upgrade to anything (even as a stepping stone).

CrystalDiskInfo and allocating my hard drives show no failed sectors.

Manual installations tell me "invalid file or directory", and digging through the logs, seem to point to a manual file for the update which exists, and I'm not sure why it's failing.

I'd post logs, but I don't know what's relevant or where to start. I'm hesitant for my next step to be using the removing .NET Framework tool, as I don't know if I can install any copy yet.

I ran the .net CleanUp Tool and removed all versions, no hiccups, reboot followed. Attempted reinstallation doesn't succeed. Then I ran Windows Update Troubleshooter and the manual reset steps again, reboot followed, and the "directory name is invalid" error still persists.

Comment: Isn't .NET Framework 4.5.1 built-into Windows 8.1?  You can't repair (nor remove) built-in versions of .NET Framework.  .NET Framework 4.5.2 is a in-place replacement upgrade for previous versions.  Is there a reason you are not installing .NET Framework 4.6.2 or 4.7.2 instead?  Why are you focusing on 4.5.2?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: The .NET Cleanup Tool would be helpful in a case like this.  As I said it **cannot** remove the built-in version of the .NET Framework but it might resolve whatever is blocking you from installing. .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: You are running Windows 8.1 Update?  Windows 8.1 Update was more or less a service pack for Windows 8.1